# How to get dropdown value based on class name

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I want to get the dropdown value based on class name

```
<select name="changeStatus" class="changeStatus1" id="changeStatus1" onChange="business_type('1')">
```

Because of some reason i don't want to get the value through the name($_POST['changeStatus'];).

I want to get through class name.

Comment: When you POST the data, the class name is not used, the "name" attribute is used as the key in $_POST array. You can change the value of the "name" attribute but there's no way you can access the posted data using class attribute as the key.

Comment: @Ananth I think I've come up with something, but in general .. user23 .. he's right, it's a bad idea.

Comment: Heh I just got bashed for giving a jQuery answer on a question that wasn't related to jQuery so I didn't give that solution here :P

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a set of dropdown all having same name with different class name. Thus what i asked to get the value based on class name. For eg: <select name="changeStatus" class="changeStatus1" id="changeStatus1" onChange="business_type('1')"> <select name="changeStatus" class="changeStatus2" id="changeStatus" onChange="business_type('2')">

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, add a hidden input field and when the form is submit, modify the value of the hidden input field.

```
<form id="myForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="hidden_input" id="hidden_input">
</form>
```

jQuery

```
$('#myForm').on('submit', function(){
    $('#hidden_input').val($('#changeStatus1').attr('class'));
});
```

Then on the backend, you can get the class of the posted input (PHP for example)

```
$className = $_POST['hidden_input'];
switch($className){
    // do Stuff...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have a set of dropdown all having same name with different class name. Thus what i asked to get the value based on class name. For eg: <select name="changeStatus" class="changeStatus1" id="changeStatus1" onChange="business_type('1')">                          <select name="changeStatus" class="changeStatus2" id="changeStatus" onChange="business_type('2')">

Comment: @user2372469 Your first problem is that you shouldn't have multiple dropdowns with the same `name` attribute. If you must keep it this way, just modify my solution to support multiple dropdowns, and thus multiple hidden inputs.